# Is it thread-safe to increment an Int32 in a Timer callback?

Tags: c#, timer, thread-safety, int32

I want to increment an integer that gets incremented in a timer event handler and read by the main and other worker threads i.e. one writer thread and multiple reader threads. Will it be thread-safe?

I have a timer in my application that runs every 5 seconds:

```
MyClock = new System.Threading.Timer(
    new TimerCallback(this.Ticker), null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite );
```

that I turn on like this:

```
MyClock.Change(5000, 5000);
```

If I increment an integer in the `Ticker` handler like this:

```
tickerCounter++;
```

can I then do a read-only access from main thread or worker threads of the same application? Will it be thread safe? Is there any chance of the reader to read a partial value, or causing a threading exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incrementing like this

```
tickerCounter++;
```

in multiple threads, without locking, is not threadsafe. You can use the `Interlocked` class to perform lock-free, threadsafe incrementing.

If only a single thread is modifying the value, with many threads reading the value, then `tickerCounter++` is threadsafe in the sense that no thread will ever suffer a partial read. Of course there is still a race condition, but even if you use `Interlocked`, there would be a race.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly: read Eric Lippert's blog post: [What is this thing you call "thread-safe"?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe) It will change how you think about thread safety, and how you ask similar questions in the future.

The reads will be *atomic* - you'll never see "half" an update - but you won't necessarily see the *latest* value. (That means that the next increment *may* see an "old" (lower) value to increment, of course.)

Additionally, the increment itself isn't inherently safe - if there were several threads incrementing at the same time, they could all read the same value, then increment locally, then write the new value - so the result could be an increment of 1, even if 10 threads were incrementing.

You should consider using [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) to perform the increment. If you *also* make the variable volatile, I *believe* you should be safe just to read it directly when you *only* want to read it.

Comment: thx, its fine for me if the value is not the latest just as long as it does not raise an exception or provide half update.

Comment: Not following Jon's advice means that sometimes your call to `tickerCounter++;` will not increase the value of `ticketCounter`.  The documentation for `Interlocked.Increment` has example code which demonstrates this problem.  This strikes me as the kind of decision that will cause a lot of confusion and wasted debugging time later (either 1 month later when someone else is debugging your code or 3 months later when you are debugging your code).

Comment: @Brian While I certainly don't disagree with almost everything you said, there is only one thread doing the increment. All other threads are reading, thus, your first sentence is not relevant.

Comment: @Marc: Who says there's only one thread incrementing? It's a `System.Threading.Timer` with no synchronization object, so each increment will occur on a thread-pool thread, but it could be a *different* thread-pool thread each time.

Comment: @JonSkeet I concede, you're right. It _could (execute the increment simultaneously on multiple timer tick threads)_ happen.

Comment: @Marc: It doesn't have to be simultaneous. It would just have to be on multiple threads without *guaranteed* memory barriers ensuring that the value read by the second incrementing thread was the value that had been written by the first incrementing thread. I mean it's *probably* going to be fine, but hey :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use [`Interlocked.Increment(ref Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) to do the incrementing? That does it as an atomic operation.

Answer (score 0):

The [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) component invokes the callback on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). There is no protection against overlapping invocations. In case the callback takes longer than the `period`, two subsequent invocations might be running on different `ThreadPool` threads at the same time. In that case it is possible to lose increments, in other words it's possible that the incremented `Int32` value will be smaller than the total number of invocations. There is no risk of threading exceptions or torn values, but there is a risk that the correctness of your application will be compromised, which is arguably even worse.

In practice, if the timer is ticking every 5 seconds and the callback does nothing more than incrementing the integer value, the probability of overlapping is zero. To get a non-zero probability of overlapping you must either do heavy work inside the handler, or set the `period` to a very small value, or both. The danger zone is for periods under ~50 msec, because this is the maximum duration that the OS can suspend a thread (according to my experiments, [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3kWlV6)). Of course relying on "safe period" estimations is not the way to write robust software. You are well advised to synchronize properly the increment of the integer, using the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement or the [`Interlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked) APIs. Starting from .NET 6 you have also the option to switch to the [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer) component, which prevents overlapping invocations naturally, by the way it is used ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval/62724908#62724908)).