# How to make a controlled infinite loop async in c#?

Tags: c#

I found this

[Run async method regularly with specified interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval)

which does half of what I want, but at the same time I want to be able to stop the loop whenever I want and then resume it as well. However while it's stopped, I don't want the infinite loop to keep running where the body gets skipped through a flag.

Basically I don't want this

```
while (true) {
    if (!paused) {
        // run work
    }
    // task delay
}
```

because then the while loop still runs.

How can I set it so that while its paused, nothing executes?

Comment: Use [Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) to off-load logic.

Comment: does that requires user input (pause/resume) or is it timer based? is it windows application?

Comment: You could use `System.Threading.Timer` and dispose of it while it is not in use and re-create it when you are ready to "resume". These timers are light weight, that would be the easiest option IMO.

Comment: You should describe what you're actually trying to do - as it is, your question is very abstract and hard to answer. It almost seems like you'd need to use some sort of workflow engine - you can easily stop any processing between steps (but not a particular step). I assume your infinite loop cannot be stopped at an arbitrary point, only at certain checkpoints (and then it'd have to pick up from there).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set it so that while its paused, nothing executes?

That's hard to answer: if you define "pause" as: `the object state remains valid while the loop doesn't use any resources` then you'll have to stop and restart it (the loop).

All other timers, including `Thread.Sleep`, `Task.Delay`s etc. will put your thread in idle/suspended mode.

If that's not sufficient for your needs, you'll need to actually stop the "infinite" loop.

It will free up thread related resources as well.

More info about sleep:

[Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx)

[More about sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815895/why-is-thread-sleep-so-harmful#8815944)

Comment: Im looking at the threading timers class but it has no pause/resume?

Comment: Yes it hasn't. What would be the meaning of a "pause" in that context?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.Threading.Timer` and dispose of it while it is not in use and re-create it when you are ready to "resume". These timers are light weight so creating and destroying them on demand is not a problem.

```
private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

public void StartResumeTimer()
{
  if(_timer == null)
    _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (e) => await DoWorkAsync(e), null, 0, 5000);
}

public void StopPauseTimer()
{
  _timer?.Dispose();
  _timer = null;
}

public async Task DoWorkAsync(object state)
{
   await Task.Delay(500); // do some work here, Task.Delay is just something to make the code compile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really adverse to timers and want it to look like a while loop, then you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _paused = null;

public async Task DoWork()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_paused != null)
        {
            await _paused.Task;
            _paused = null;
        }
        //run work
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}

public void Pause()
{
    _paused = _paused ?? new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
}

public void UnPause()
{
    _paused?.SetResult(true);
}
```