# Launch Task periodically

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to launch a method in a separated thread periodically (every minute). I was using `System.Timers.Timer` but I realize that Timers cause memory leaks.

I need to remove Timers and use task. The first idea is launch a Task in the following way:

```
_taskWork = Task.Factory.StartNew( DoWork );
```

And in the DoWork method:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    While(true)
    {
        // Stuff here

        Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to launch a task avoiding this approach?

Comment: Maybe to look into some library like `quartz.net`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `Thread.Sleep` with tasks, instead use `await Task.Delay(60000);`, and make your method async. Also, you probably shouldn't be using `Task.Factory.StartNew`, instead, after making your method `private async Task DoWork()`, simply call it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Timers cause memory leaks"?

Comment: Also, how do you figure that timers cause memory leaks?

Comment: Timers are *designed* for this use case. *Misuse* of timers may have led you to having a memory leak but that would have been about *your code*, not timers themselves. Unfortunately, you've not shown us the code that "causes memory leaks".

Comment: checkout `hangfire` to execute code periodically(cron jobs). (https://www.hangfire.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar Method : The async equivalent is a while loop with Task.Delay (which internally uses a System.Threading.Timer):

```
public async Task PeriodicFooAsync(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await FooAsync();
        await Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken)
    }
}
```

This Work fine for me please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval) this for more understanding.