# How to run a function every minute comparing old number to new number?

Tags: c#

I'd like to run a function every minute to achieve the following:

- Run function every minute
- Run MySQL command to get count
- Store the count into a variable
- Compare the result to old result every minute
- Create an If statement if number is not same to previous number.

Here is what I have:

```
 private void Method()
{
    int count = int.MinValue;
    int prev_count = int.MinValue;


    while (true)
    {

        //Get count from MySQL table
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select count(*) from table;", conn))
            {
                count = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }


        if (count != prev_count)
        {

            prev_count = count;
        }

    }
}
```

My question is - is the correct way of coding this to compare the old number to new number? and also, how can I make this function run every minute?

Comment: If the process is that simple you might want to just use `Thread.Sleep(60000)` to make the code wait 1min.

Comment: Yes, `if (count != prev_count)` is the correct way to compare the old number to new number.

Comment: @devcrp at the bottom of my code?

Comment: yep, last line in side your `while`

Comment: Pretty much everything else is wrong though. Start with understanding what `ExecuteNonQuery` does, and, consequently, what gets stored in `count`.

Comment: @GSerg `ExecuteScalar()` should be the correct one? Because it returns me one row compared to the one I am using will be multiple rows etc..

Comment: Yes, it should be. Then think about who is calling `Method()` and is it correct that it never returns, as opposed to e.g. returning from it and having the thing that currently calls it call it every 60 seconds (including with the aforementioned `Thread.Sleep(60000)`).

Comment: @GSerg You've lost me.. can you expand please?

Comment: Where would you call this function?

Comment: @LV98 when the dashboard screen loads.

Comment: The idea is to notify the user is record has been inserted into MySQL

Comment: Hello, i would recommend looking at the following post as well [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval), it makes use of TPL-library in which you get extra benifits such as cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

Here how to call an event hendeler to track each given time.
Hope this will help you.

```
private static System.Timers.Timer timer;

    private static void YourFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        timer.Start();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000; // time to configure
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(YourFunction);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Is that 5 minutes or 5 seconds?

Comment: @LionBar 1000 is euqal to 1 second. So a minute will be 60 * 1000 which means you have to make it 60000. Feel free for any question :)