# How to pause timer till procedure within finishes in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I am building a service.

This service process and move files from one forlder to another.

There is a timer in this service that check every minute to see if there are files to move and move them

what is happening is when it starts it moves the files but if the number of files is big it takes more than 1 minute which leads to call the same procedure again and get errors

I want the timer to be paused till the function within finishes then back again

here is my code

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = IntervalLength;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
            timer.Start();
    }

    public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.Stop();

        DO();

        this.Start();

    }

    private void DO()
    {
     //Process and move files
    }
```

I added Stop to stop the timer but Start() is give this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'XMI2DBSrv' does not contain a definition for 'Start' and
> no accessible extension method 'Start' accepting a first argument of
> type 'XMI2DBSrv' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)   XMI2DB  E:\XMI2DBsrv.cs 73  Active

how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean `sender.Start()`?

Comment: @Loocid sender gives error too

Comment: Did you cast it as a timer? Eg `((Timer)sender).Start()`

Comment: I've edited my comment.

Comment: This may give you some ideas: [Run async method regularly with specified interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval)

Comment: @Loocid Please put your comment as an answer i will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `OnTimer` method, you are using `this`. However `this` refers to the class that contains the method, rather than the Timer object.

You need to call Start and Stop on the Timer object, which is `sender` in this case.

Therefore, what you are looking for is `((Timer)sender).Start();`.