# Bool variable is blocking multithread task

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, queue

I have a queue of data that must be processed.

```
public static ConcurrentQueue<Data> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Data>();
```

A bool variable that blocks thread generating if a current thread is running.

```
private static bool busy = false;
```

A timer that runs each 5000ms and runs a thread to process that queue sequentially.

```
timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
timer.Interval = 5000;
timer.Enabled = true;

private static void Timer_Elapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!busy)
    {
        Thread thread= new Thread(Task);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

And the task function that must be run by every generated thread in background:

```
private static void Task()
{
    Console.WriteLine("im busy");
    busy= true;
    Data data= null;
    if (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        bool ok= queue.TryDequeue(out data);
        if (ok && data!= null)
        {
            try{
                LongTaskSync(data);
            }catch(Exception){
                Console.WriteLine("Error in longtasksync");
            }
        }
    }
   
    Console.WriteLine("im not busy");
    busy= false;
}
```

The problem is that `busy` variable sometimes get stuck to `true` and never becomes `false`. Don't know why. So queue gets full and no threads are generated to process the queue because the

```
if (!busy)
{
    Thread thread= new Thread(Task);
    thread.Start();
}
```

block is never reached.

Comment: If you change the definition to `private static volatile bool busy = false;` does the problem go away?

Comment: No, i also tried with `volatile` and the problem is still there

Comment: You sure that `LongTaskSync()` isn't throwing an exception? Because if it does, `busy` will be stuck at `true`.

Comment: Try adding a lock `object` and use the lock whenever you access the `busy` variable. (I would also consider changing `busy` into a private property and use the lock inside its accessors)
Example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

Comment: Most likely you're either stuck in a loop or crashed the thread (Exception thrown) in `LongTaskSync(data)` call, so the `busy = false` is never reached.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you beat me to it, lol!

Comment: @MatthewWatson I also thought the same, so I closed that line inside a `try-catch` block to be sure that `busy=false` is executed, but it won't work too..

Comment: I think it would be useful to have an idea what `LongTaskSync` is doing, there might be some loop or anything. For example if you change `LongTaskSync(data)` with simple `Thread.Sleep(n)` does the problem go away?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to prevent overlapping executions of the `LongTaskSync` method. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval) question for ideas about simpler ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, indeed thats the aim of my question, I want that function to execute atomicaly, it cannot be never executed concurrently because it involves Database operations. But I dont find how your link can help me to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not posting this as a direct answer to your question, but if you're open to an alternative approach, I can suggest you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<Data> Dequeue()
{
    while (queue.TryDequeue(out Data data))
    {
        yield return data;
    }
}

IObservable<long> query =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
            .Select(_ => Dequeue().ToObservable())
            .Concat();

IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(data => LongTaskSync(data));
```

That handles all of the concurrency for you. There's no need to check any `busy` variable.

I prefer not to run code in the subscrinbe, so to run it in the query itself, and to ensure that only one `LongTaskSync` runs at a time, you can use an `EventLoopScheduler` like this:

```
IObservable<Unit> query =
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new EventLoopScheduler(),
                els =>
                    Observable
                        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
                        .Select(_ => Dequeue().ToObservable())
                        .Concat()
                        .SelectMany(data =>
                            Observable
                                .Start(() => LongTaskSync(data), els)));


IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe();
```

Comment: But this is not continiously checking the queue, this only executes a single time right?

Comment: @E.Williams - Good catch. I fixed it.

Comment: Good, one question: is `Observable.Start(() => LongTaskSync(data))` running on background thread or on main thread?

Comment: @E.Williams - It's effectively running on the thread pool.

Comment: However this is not preventing overlapping executions of the sync function right?

Comment: @E.Williams - Ah, I'll have to make a change. Give me a couple of hours.

Comment: @E.Williams - Fixed - two alternatives on offer now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to invoke a synchronous action periodically on background threads, enforcing a non overlapping execution policy. A relatively easy way to do it is to implement an asynchronous loop, based on the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) method or the new (.NET 6) [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer) class. Here is a `PeriodicTimer`-based implementation:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

Task consumer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    using var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
    while (true)
    {
        try { await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(cts.Token); }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { break; }

        try
        {
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out var data))
            {
                LongTaskSync(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in LongTaskSync");
        }
    }
});
```

The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method offloads the asynchronous loop on the `ThreadPool`. The [`WaitForNextTickAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.waitfornexttickasync) suspends the loop until the next tick of the timer.
The [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource) can be used in order to stop the loop before terminating the process, for a clean and graceful termination:

```
cts.Cancel();
consumer.Wait(); // or await
```

This way the process will not be killed in the midst of a `LongTaskSync` execution.

If you prefer a `Task.Delay`-based implementation, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval/62724908#62724908) for the basic idea.

In case you would like to process the data in the queue as soon as they are available, and not periodically, you could look at the [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) or the [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) components.

Answer (score -1):

It was easier than I thought, just using a `Mutex` instead of a boolean var.

```
private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();

private static void Task()
{
    Console.WriteLine("im busy");
    //busy= true;
    mut.WaitOne();
    Data data= null;
    if (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        bool ok= queue.TryDequeue(out data);
        if (ok && data!= null)
        {
            try{
                LongTaskSync(data);
            }catch(Exception){
                Console.WriteLine("Error in longtasksync");
            }
        }
    }
   
    Console.WriteLine("im not busy");
    //busy= false;
    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}
```