# Await inside System.Threading.Timer callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, timer, background

I am doing an ASP.NET Web API and have a `BackgroundService` like this:

[image]

Inside `Doing`, I to await a task 1:

[image]

The problem is with the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))` the `ExecuteAsync` will do create a new `Doing()` without waiting for my task to be done.

The console result :

[image]

How can I resolve this? Or is there a way to achieve a background task with await for the task completion?

Comment: **Please** don't use pictures of code in your questions, copy and paste your code as text, and then format it as `code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `Timer`.
Instead set up a `loop` and use `Task.Delay` for the wait period.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
    
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {                            
        await Doing();
        await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

See an example in [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#implementing-ihostedservice-with-a-custom-hosted-service-class-deriving-from-the-backgroundservice-base-class).

Comment: Or you can use the new (.NET 6) [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer) class, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval/62724908#62724908), for a consistently periodic ticking of the timer.