# Should Timer be waiting for callback to finish before firing a new one?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I am using the `System.Threading.Timer` class in one of my projects and I've noticed that the callback methods are called before the previous ones get to finish which is different than what I was expecting.

For example the following code

```
var delta = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
var timer = new Timer(TestClass.MethodAsync, null, TimeSpan.Zero, delta);

static class TestClass
{
    static int i = 0;
    public static async void MethodAsync(object _)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("method " + i + "started");

        await Task.Delay(10000);
        
        Console.WriteLine("method " + i + "finished");
    }
}
```

has this output

```
method 1started
method 2started
method 3started
method 4started
method 5started
method 6started
method 7started
method 8started
method 9started
method 10started
method 11started
method 11finished
method 12started
method 12finished
```

Which of course is not thread safe. What I was expecting is that a new call would be made to the callback method after the previous call has succeeded and additionally after the `delta` period is elapsed.

**What I am looking for is where in the docs from Microsoft is this behavior documented and maybe if there is a built in way to make it wait for the callback calls to finish before starting new ones**

Comment: I would have timer call MethodAsync() only once and restart the timer at the end of the method.

Comment: If thread safety is needed you can wrap the code in MethodAsync() with lock().

Comment: @emilsteen I know we can have workarounds, I'm looking more for the official documentation and a common robust approach if there is any

Comment: I'm looking at Microsoft [System.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) and it says "If processing of the `Elapsed` event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another `ThreadPool` thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant." My read is that the answer to your question **Should Timer be waiting** would be 'no' if using `System.Timer` but there are other `Timer` classes of course. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm also looking at Microsoft documentation for [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator which says, "The await operator doesn't block the thread that evaluates the `async` method. When the `await` operator suspends the enclosing `async` method, **the control returns to the caller of the method**. My interpretation is that even if the `Timer` _did_ wait for the callback to finish, your use of the `await` operator gives an explicit directive to return from the callback _before_ executing the Task.Delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of overlapping event handlers is inherent with the classic multithreaded .NET timers (the `System.Threading.Timer` and the `System.Timers.Timer`). Attempting to solve this problem while remaining on the event-publisher-subscriber model is difficult, tricky, and error prone. The .NET 6 introduced a new timer, the [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer), that attempts to solve this problem once and for all. Instead of handling an event, you start an asynchronous loop and `await` the [`PeriodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.waitfornexttickasync) method on each iteration. Example:

```
class TestClass : IDisposable
{
    private int i = 0;
    private PeriodicTimer _timer;

    public async Task StartAsynchronousLoop()
    {
        if (_timer != null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        _timer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Iteration {i} started");
            await Task.Delay(10000); // Simulate an I/O-bound operation
            Console.WriteLine($"Iteration {i} finished");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() => _timer?.Dispose();
}
```

This way there is no possibility for overlapping executions, provided that you will start only one asynchronous loop.

The `await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync()` returns `false` when the timer is disposed. You can also stop the loop be passing a `CancellationToken` as argument. When the token is canceled, the `WaitForNextTickAsync` will complete with an `OperationCanceledException`.

In case the periodic action is not asynchronous, you can offload it to the `ThreadPool`, by wrapping it in [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run):

```
await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(10000)); // Simulate a blocking operation
```

If you are targeting a .NET platform older than .NET 6, you can find alternatives to the `PeriodicTimer` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval).

Answer (score 3):

**What I am looking for is where in the docs from Microsoft is this behavior documented...**

[System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-6.0)

> If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

[System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.00)

> The callback method executed by the timer should be reentrant, because it is called on ThreadPool threads.

For `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a446b4cc-67ab-4294-85fd-2922ddaf8de2/does-timertick-need-to-be-reentrant?forum=netfxbcl) asserts that the event *does* wait. The documentation doesn't seem very specific, but in the Microsoft [Timer.Tick Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) official example the code shows turning the timer off and on *in the handler*. So it seems that, regardless, steps are taken to prevent ticks and avoid reentrancy.

**...and if there is a built in way to make it wait for the callback calls to finish before starting new ones.**

According to the first Microsoft [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-6.0) (you might consider this a workaround, but it's straight from the horse's mouth):

> One way to resolve this race condition is to set a flag that tells the event handler for the Elapsed event to ignore subsequent events.

The way I personally go about achieving this objective this is to call `Wait(0)` on the synchronization object of choice as a robust way to ignore reentrancy without having timer events piling up in a queue:

```
static SemaphoreSlim _sslim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
public static async void MethodAsync(object _)
{
    if (_sslim.Wait(0))
    {
        try
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine($"method {i} started @ {DateTime.Now}");

            await Task.Delay(10000);

            Console.WriteLine($"method {i} finished @ {DateTime.Now}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            _sslim.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

In which case your `MethodAsync` generates this output:

[image]