# Running a task periodically without blocking the main thread C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am trying to send a keep-alive HTTP request each 30 minutes. However I have other methods to be called at the time in between, so what I tried to do is:

```cs
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    while(true){
        await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0,30,0), CancellationToken.None);
        await FooTask();
    }
});
```

Am I using it properly?

Comment: How about a timer?

Comment: Related: [Run async method regularly with specified interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval).

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing it properly? No. You say you want a loop, but don't write a loop. You're also using the wrong task creation function:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        await FooTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
});
```

There's also [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0) which follows a similar pattern, you do your action and `await` the next tick.

Comment: Just remembered of putting the loop, thank you for the directions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework.

Then you can just do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30.0))
        .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => FooTask()))
        .Subscribe();
```

Calling `subscription.Dispose()` shuts it down. It's nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `Task.Run()` is effectively fire and forget.

If you try to 'wait' for a `Task.Run()` to complete it will return almost immediately because it's 'task' is to launch the inner operation.
Once it's done that it's `IsCompleted`. It does not hook onto the inner operation.

So suppose you have 3 long-running sub-tasks, JobA(), JobB() and JobC(), to be completed sequentially...

```
public bool ExecuteLongRunningTasks(CancellationToken cancelToken = default)
{
    if (!_JobACompleted)
    {
        JobA();
        _JobACompleted = true;

        if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return false;
    }

    if (!_JobBCompleted)
    {
        JobB();
        _JobBCompleted = true;

        if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return false;
    }

    JobC();
    _AllJobsCompleted = true;

    return true;
}
```

... and that at at some point the UI thread may require the results of these 3 sub-tasks (which have been launched asynchronously), then it stands to reason that you will allow a long running sub-task to complete asynchronously, and then have the better performing UI thread complete the uncompleted sub-tasks.

To achieve this I have to use `StartNew()` for the asynchronous operations because StartNew(), 'by default', hooks onto the operation it is launching...

```
public bool AsyncExecute()
{
    // Property accessor that does a few sanity checks.
    if (!ClearToLoadAsync)
        return false;

    _AsyncActive = true;

    _AsyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(
        () => 
        {
            ExecuteLongRunningTasks(_CancelToken);
            _AsyncActive = false;
            return true;
        },
        default, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

    return true;
}
```

... and if the UI thread needs the results it uses the much maligned `Wait()`...

```
public bool SyncExecute()
{
    // Just a property accessor that does some trivial deadlock and completion checks.
    if (!ClearToLoadSync)
        return false;

    if (_AsyncActive)
    {
       // Post a cancel request and wait.
        _CancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        _AsyncTask.Wait();
    }

    if (!_AllJobsCompleted)
    {
       // Execute any outstanding long running tasks synchronously.
       return ExecuteLongRunningTasks();
    }

    return true;
}
```

If anyone has a solution that achieves the same with Task.Run() I would love to see how it is done because I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score -1):

You likely want to use `Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNewAsync()`, per the [remarks in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=net-7.0#remarks). `Task.Run()` is recommended unless you need the extra options in `Task.Factory.StartNewAsync()` (ex: Task Creation Options, Task Scheduler, Parameter Passing that `Task.Run()` does not cover).

[`Task.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0) will queue the task to run on the current thread pool, and it will also return a handle to the task in case you want to Wait for completion or Cancel the task, as shown in the below example.

```
CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = src.Token;
Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while(true){
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0,30,0), ct);
        await FooTask();
    }
}, ct);


// Do some other stuff while your task runs

// Cancel Your Task, OR
ct.Cancel();

// Wait for your task to finish
try
{
    t.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    // Handle the exception
}
```