# .NET 7 - Run timer callback in my TaskScheduler or my SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to build a library that internally executes task in an exclusive TaskScheduler built as following:

```cs
schedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(TaskScheduler.Default, 1);
simulationFactoryTask = new TaskFactory(schedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler);
```

I use the `System.Threading.Timer` class:

```cs
timer = new Timer(Tick, this, startTime, deltaTime);
```

That periodically calls my `Tick` method:

```cs
static void Tick(object? state)
{
    var self = state as MyTimerScheduler;

    // fake computation
    Thread.Sleep(10_000);
}
```

The issue is that the `Tick` method is executed inside a different thread and not in the one inside my schedulerPair.

One solution is to schedule a new Task like that:

```cs
static void Tick(object? state)
{
    var self = state as MyTimerScheduler;

    // This shouldn't be needed
    self.simulationFactoryTask.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // fake computation
        Thread.Sleep(10_000);
    });
}
```

Is it possible to schedule `Tick` inside schedulerPair `TaskScheduler`?

Comment: Aren't you worried that the duration of the work might be longer than the interval between ticks, causing an ever increasing number of tasks scheduled through your `schedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler`?

Comment: Yes, since the computational work is a simulation step, often the majority of task execution time is less than deltaTime (hyperparameter to be defined). But sure it's something to be aware of.

Comment: You can find some ideas about solving this problem here: [Run async method regularly with specified interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> The timer delegate is specified when the timer is constructed, and cannot be changed. **The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a `ThreadPool` thread supplied by the system**.

And

> `System.Threading.Timer` is a simple, lightweight timer that uses callback methods and is served **by thread pool threads**.

Comment: Is there any alternative to System.Threading.Timer that can do that?

Comment: @EduBic Not that I know of. Also not sure that using schedulers would be the best option here. But without full overview it is hard to tell.

Comment: Would you just use a raw `Thread` with a `ConcurrentQueue` of Task?

Comment: @EduBic yes, that what I was thinking about.