# Implementing Tasks, await and async for background work

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I am new to Tasks and its associated keywords in C#. My goal is to setup a background thread/task that will continuously poll a server every n seconds. Using the .NET TPL library, is the following structure of methods and fields an appropriate way to accomplish this?

```
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private CancellationToken _ct;

    public override async Task StartSomeServiceAsync()
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _ct = _cts.Token;

        await Task.Run(() => this.Work(_ct));
        
        //TODO Do some reporting, system management/cleanup etc... 
          after the task has been cancelled
    }

    protected override void Work(CancellationToken ct)
    {        
        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //Make network calls, collect data
            //Notify data subscribers of new data received from network
        }
    }

    public override void StopSomeService()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
```

The owning object of this code can either start this background work using a StartSomeServiceAsync() call, and if external conditions are met, then it would stop the background thread/task by cancelling the task via a StopSomeService() call.

Any input is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: Look into PeriodicTimer class.

Comment: Related: [Run async method regularly with specified interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval).

Comment: Btw: `while(true) { if (isCanceled) break; }` doesn't make sense. You could do much more readable `while(!isCanceled){ ...}`

Comment: @Fildor Agreed, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread for long running work. This is not the intended usage of the `ThreadPool`. Instead of the `Task.Run`, it is preferable to use a dedicated thread by using the advanced [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) API with the [`LongRunning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) option:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.Work(_ct), CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Instead of dedicating a thread and blocking it with `Thread.Sleep(5000);`, you could also use a timer, like the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) or the async-enabled [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer). Nevertheless the dedicated thread has the advantage that it will tick consistently every 5 seconds. The built-in timers depend heavily on the `ThreadPool`, so they might tick inconsistently in case the `ThreadPool` happens to be saturated for prolonged time spans.